# exterior problem for fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does there exist a theory of fractional laplacian on exterior domains such as 
$$
  \ \  \left\{\begin{aligned}
(-\Delta)^{s} u&= 0  &&\text{in } \mathbb R^N\setminus \mathbb B  \\
u & =g &&\text{ in } \mathbb  B
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
$$
where $\mathbb  B$ is a unit ball, $N\geq 1$ and $s\in (0, 1).$
Does there exist a Poisson kernel for this type of problem. Is the solution for the problem be expressible as the combination of the Poisson kernel and $g.$